# In the Stack Overflow blog, what is an "affinity coding group"?

Tags: discussion, blog

In the blog post [New decade, new survey goals (& reminder to take the survey before it closes next week!)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/19/new-decade-new-survey-goals-reminder-to-take-the-survey-before-it-closes-next-week/), which refers to "gender and cultural gaps", the term "affinity coding group" is used:

> In order to achieve our goal of obtaining a data set representative of
>   everyone who codes, and, more importantly, continuing the work that is
>   necessary to serve underrepresented groups of coders who may not feel
>   welcome on Stack Overflow, we need to reach beyond our networks. We’re
>   working on this internally by strategically advertising the Survey to
>   followers of **affinity coding groups** and emphasizing our desire to
>   learn about the coding universe as a whole, no matter where they live
>   or what websites they frequent for troubleshooting technical problems.
>   These efforts can only take us so far, though, so we’re asking for
>   your help.

This blog post is the only hit I got when I googled for the phrase. As a non-American, I hadn't even heard the term "affinity group" before.

What's an "affinity coding group"? Is it a group with a common technical interest, or a group of people in the same "minority group" (is that the currently used term?)?

Comment: I'm an American and I haven't heard of an "affinity group" either.

Comment: So they just look at their competitors to see what they do better.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_group):

> An affinity group is a group formed around a shared interest or common goal, to which individuals formally or informally belong.